# R Data Frame remove rows with max values from all columns

Tags: r

Hello I have the data frame and I need to remove all the rows with max values from each columns.
Example

```
   A B C
1  2 3 5
2  4 1 1
3  1 4 3
4  2 1 1
```

So the output is:

```
   A B C
4  2 1 1
```

Is there any quick way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `%in%`

```
df1[!seq_len(nrow(df1)) %in% sapply(df1, which.max),]
#  A B C
#4 2 1 1
```

If there are ties for maximum values in each row, then do

```
df1[!Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1, function(x) x== max(x))),]
```

Comment: There are ties for maxiumum values. Your first line is working very well, but the second one for ties returns me an error saying "Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  ‘max’ not meaningful for factors "

Comment: @LucasPG I assumed that you have only numeric columns.  If there are non-numeric, there is no point in taking max for that column.  Or just exclude the column

Comment: Right the last column is not numerical. I am very begginer with R, can You guide me how to do that?

Comment: @LucasPG.  `i1 <- sapply(df1, is.numeric); df1[!Reduce("|", lapply(df1[i1], function(x) x==max(x))),]`

Comment: That returns me the boolean value which column is numeric, It returns me TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE. How can I remove rows with max values from all columns with ties?

Comment: @LucasPG I think you haven't run the second line i.e. `df1[!Reduce("`

Comment: Yes my bad, That solved my problem. Thank You so much Sir for Your time .

Answer (score 1):

```
df[-sapply(df, which.max),]
#  A B C
#4 2 1 1
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(A = c(2L, 4L, 1L, 2L), B = c(3L, 1L, 4L, 1L), 
    C = c(5L, 1L, 3L, 1L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L))
```