# Removing final row in column or row with the highest value in a column

Tags: r, rows, stat

Is it possible to remove the last row in a column or the maximum value in a column?
I am trying to remove the last number in a column of numbers that goes from lowest to highest number.
I need the last row removed for the column.

Example Data:

```
Column 1
1
2
3
4
5
```

Example output:

```
Column 1
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: The following code is suggested in another post for a similar problem: `df1[!seq_len(nrow(df1)) %in% sapply(df1, which.max),]` See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078940/r-data-frame-remove-rows-with-max-values-from-all-columns. Does that help to answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the row with max value this way. Say, where x is the dataframe.
x[x$column1!=max(x$column1),]

Comment: Does it help answer your question?